# Как можно улучшить абстрактный класс?

Tags: android, java

Есть класс для работы с звонками на андроиде:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import java.util.Date;

public abstract class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

//The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
private static Date callStartTime;
private static boolean isIncoming;
private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
    } else {
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int state = 0;
        if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }

        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
    }
}

//Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
}

protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
}

protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
}

protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
}

protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
}

//Deals with actual events

//Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
//Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
    if (lastState == state) {
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;
            onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            } else if (isIncoming) {
                onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            } else {
                onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            }
            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
}
```

}

Вроде все отлично, теперь можно сделать так:

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

@Override
protected void onIncomingCallStarted(String number, Date start) {
}

@Override
protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(String number, Date start) {
}

@Override
protected void onIncomingCallEnded(String number, Date start, Date end) {
}

@Override
protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(String number, Date start, Date end) {
}

@Override
protected void onMissedCall(String number, Date start) {
}
```

}

И все прекрасно, в любой момент времени понятно, что происходит. Но техлид сказал, что это какое-то мракобесие, что много лишнего. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я согласен с техлидом.

Comment: Единственное, что не понятно, это зачем свитч? И сам метод onCallStateChanged? Почему в ресивере просто не вызывать отдельные методы под это дело? А что именно у Вашего техлида вызвало спазмы мракобесия? Реализация абстрактного класса или само его наличие? Если второе - меняйте техлида :-)

Comment: @Чад, вот как раз его это смущает. И еще статик поля, он говорит, надо без них как-то. Да, возможно, метод лишний, это да, но зато повторно, что он делает.

Comment: @Izobara, да, статики проглядел, думал, это константы. Не используйте статики как переменные, если у вас будет много потоков, они взорвут вам Мозг. И представьте, что будет, если Вы создадите два экземпляра класса или даже два наследника класса сделаете... У Вас вся логика работы пойдёт по звезде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Исключите статик переменные:**

Если Вы создадите 2 и более экземпляра класса, то логика работы Вашего метода, использующего эти переменные, будет нарушена.

**Упростите работу с ресивером:**

Например,

```
String action = intent.getAction();
String extra_state = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
if(action.equals("...NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")){
    internalNewOutgoingCall(intent);
}
else if(extra_state.equals("RINGING")){
    internalRinging(intent);
}
```

Ещё бы избавиться от if'ов, но это уже так... если ресурсы девать некуда.

По Вашему коду непонятно, зачем и что вы делаете. Старайтесь делать изолированные куски.

Answer (score 1):

1. Эм-м..., а почему ваш класс, собтвесно говоря, декларируется как абстрактный? Это тоже может вызвать спазмы мракобесия (ну, кроме статических переменных, естественно).
2. Зачем `onCallStateChanged()` объявлен как публичный? Это некий интимный, вроде, метод, и хорошо бы объявить его приватным.
3. Неплохо бы создать протектед конструктор (раз уж класс абстрактный), где провести инициализацию переменных.
4. Опять же, раз класс абстрактный, знаменитые методы типа `protected void onIncomingCallEnded` объявить бы публичными абстрактными (все равно они пустые, так пусть будут абстрактные).

Comment: Я от него наследуюсь, как вы могли отметить, переопределяю метод и могу с ними работать.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, мне кажется, абстрактный - то это гуд, он сам по себе бесполезный. Без переопределённых методов пустышек он вообще не нужен. Зачем разрешать программисту делать бесполезные вещи?

Comment: См. апдейт (предложения по улучшению).